# Codeigniter multilanguage uri without language part

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, multilingual, codeigniter-url

I've searched a lot and found even more topics on CI's multilanguage URLs. But most of the answers have no longer working links to CI wiki or doesn't explain a bit of what I want.

My default is a non English language, but I want controllers and methods named in English. I also don't want language segment appear in my URL (at least not for default language).

Eg.:

- Default uri - example.com/blogas/irasas/123
- English uri - example.com/blog/item/123 or example.com/en/blog/item/123

Links in both languages should call Blog::item()

Generating uris should be similar - `site_url('blog/item/123');` should result a link in user language:

- Default - example.com/blogas/irasas/123
- English - example.com/blog/item/123 or example.com/en/blog/item/123

User language should be set in a cookie or session preferably.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Using latest CI 2.2.0

I believe [this solution for 2.1](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) should work, but I can't figure out how URI's should be translated (where to put translations) and how to remove language part from URI.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am wrong but what I understood is that you are trying to generate different urls based on active language using same words in `site_url`. If this is correct you can simply translate your words using language helper.

```
site_url(lang('blog_item_url') . '123);
```

And in your english langugae file.

```
$lang['blog_item_url']        =   "blog/item/";
```

And in your other langugae

```
$lang['blog_item_url']        =   "blogas/irasas/";
```

And define **routes** in **route.php** in configurations.

```
$route['blog/item/(:num)'] = "blog/item/$1";
$route['blogas/irasas/(:num)'] = "blog/item/$1";
```

Comment: And what about removing language part from URL? I also noticed that now it redirects to controller if I go to example.com (it redirects to example.com/en/blog) - is there a simple way to get rid of that too?

Comment: Are you using a library for multilingual?

Comment: I've done everything like in a tutorial I've posted a link to (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n)

Comment: I'm trying now to make routing work and I have to define all routes like `$route['lang/blogas/irasas/(:any)'] = 'blog/item/$1';`. Otherwise I get 404 error if I skip the `lang/` part. I can't believe there's no way to make multilanguage simpler in CI :/

Comment: Do not use that library and store active language in your session data. And then use custom routing with translations.